# How to reliably turn HTML into a PDF

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf

I am working on an application that generates lots of simple reports. The report is in a table element. It is just text, nothing fancy. The size (both columns and rows) are unknown to me before runtime, so some could be just a few columns while others could be quite wide.

The application is written in HTML and AngularJS. It gets its data from a C# Web API however the API cannot be changed to return a formatted report. :( So I need to do it on the client side.

I tried this component (https://github.com/hearsid/ng-html-to-pdf-save) however it doesn't like the table element at all, and just prints out the last column of a fairly small table. I do love how simple it is to implement however.

What client-side PDF solutions have you used that work reliably? Angular friendly solutions are welcome but not required. We will be moving to Angular 5 soon anyway.

Thanks

Comment: The library you linked-to just uses `html2canvas` to render to a canvas then saves that inside a PDF, presumably as an embedded raster image - that's very inefficient and doesn't result in a searchable PDF file.

Comment: Have you seen this library instead? https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF - granted, you have to issue PDF commands directly, but it will give you "correct" output.

Comment: check this link - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JKKNMK

Answer (score 2):

As @Dai suggested,  you can easily achieve that using jspdf.

```
var doc = new jsPDF()
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    },
    '.controls': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
// All units are in the set measurement for the document
// This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
doc.save('how-to-reliably-turn-html-into-a-pdf.pdf');
```

Please find the below working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var doc = new jsPDF()

      var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
          return true;
        },
        '.controls': function(element, renderer) {
          return true;
        }
      };

      // All units are in the set measurement for the document
      // This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
      doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      });

      doc.save('how-to-reliably-turn-html-into-a-pdf.pdf');

    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```